# how to get the firstDayof the month at the beginning of time?

Tags: javascript, date

So i have a function, that returns the firstDay of the month . What I want exactly is time to be set to starting of the date i.e. midnight.

```
function firstDayOfMonth() {
  var d = new Date(Date.apply(null, arguments));
  d.setDate(1);
  return d.toISOString();
}
```

Comment: d.setDate(1).startOf('days')

Comment: *"...at the beginning of time"* - Well that would depend on your scientific and religious beliefs, wouldn't it? According to the Bible, the first day was a Sunday...

Comment: by beginning of time I meant, 1st of july 2016 midnight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try after your `d.setDate(1)`

```
d.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

or for local time

```
d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```